# Missing required parameters for [Route: developer.variants.store] [URI: developer/{store}/products/{products}/variants]

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this route in my developer group in web.php

```
    Route::get('{store}/products/{products}/variants', [
    'as' => 'variants.create',
    'uses' => 'VariantsController@create',
]);

Route::post('{store}/products/{products}/variants', [
    'as' => 'variants.store',
    'uses' => 'VariantsController@store',
]);
```

in which the {store} is a slug, and {products} is the uuid.

now my VariantsController@create:

```
    public function create($store, $id)
{
    $store = Store::where('slug', $store)->firstOrFail();
    $product = $store->products()->findOrFail($id);
    return view('devoptions.products.variants', compact('store'));
}
```

and my variants.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            {!! Form::open([ 'route' => ['developer.variants.store', $store->slug], 
            'method' => 'POST' ]) !!}
       <div class="col-sm-12">
           <div class="page-header">
                //more code here
```

and I am getting the error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: developer.variants.store] [URI: developer/{store}/products/{products}/variants]. (View: /Users/Kit/nowna-core-php-api/resources/views/devoptions/products/variants.blade.php)

I have tried passing the $product but I do not know how, even if I try to, it does not work. please help.

EDIT: I have tried passing another parameter:

```
                {!! Form::open([ 'route' => ['developer.variants.store', $store->slug, $product->uuid], 
            'method' => 'POST' ]) !!}
```

but now it gives me another error:

> Undefined variable: store (View: /Users/Sample/project/resources/views/devoptions/products/variants.blade.php)

Comment: Run `php artisan view:clear` and post the whole of variants.blade.php if the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is missing [] in second param and $product->uuid, try this:

```
{!! Form::open([ 'route' => ['developer.variants.store', [$store->slug, $product->uuid]], 
        'method' => 'POST' ]) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{!! Form::open([ 'route' => ['developer.variants.store', $store->slug, $product->uuid], 
            'method' => 'POST' ]) !!}
```

Comment: already tried that, now it says that Undefined variable: store (View: variants.blade.php)

Comment: Please edit your question, post variants.blade.php and the new error message.